# Snowflake Parsing Unnamed Json Array in Table

Tags: arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having great difficulty in using Snowflake to parse some JSON data, I have an unnamed array in one of my tables and want to break it apart as part of a query

```
 [{"CodeName":"443","CodeQuantity":6}]
 [{"CodeName":"550","CodeQuantity":4}]
 [{"CodeName":"293","CodeQuantity":1},{"CodeName":"294","CodeQuantity":3}]
```

My Query is this

```
SELECT CODES
FROM CODETABLE
```

I am having problems parsing the json to split the codename / codequantity into individual elements and rows.

Comment: Are these strings? Variants? Can you share the results of a query that didn't work?

Comment: Well I am trying to find an example of how to break my array apart. I am having difficulty doing it as my array has no name. The field in the table is as following `16
CODES
VARCHAR(1000)
COLUMN
Y
N
N
`

Comment: The field in Snowflake is a Varchar, and The Codename is a String, and the CodeQuantity is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are each separate records, stored as varchar, then you simply need to use the `parse_json()` function to make them into json before flattening and parsing:

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES 
        ('[{"CodeName":"443","CodeQuantity":6}]'),
        ('[{"CodeName":"550","CodeQuantity":4}]'),
        ('[{"CodeName":"293","CodeQuantity":1},{"CodeName":"294","CodeQuantity":3}]')
     ) x (varchar_data)
)
SELECT y.value:CodeName::number,
       y.value:CodeQuantity::varchar
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN (input=>parse_json(varchar_data)) y;
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. I was able to change it to look up from my table and pull the data that I need.